# Grails: JSON to beans - custom field name

Tags: grails, data-binding

In my Grails application for POST request I am receiving some data as JSON in with keys in broken English.

```
{
    "emplId": "1234",
    "emplyNm": "Priyank Thakkar"
}
```

I am translating this JSON to a Groovy bean

**Employee.groovy**

```
class Employee {
    String id
    String name
}
```

Now, Grails is forcing me to use same key names as attributes of my bean class and I don't intend to do that. (This is not a domain class, this is a bean.)

How do I achieve this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Use Grails Command Object. 
http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects

Whether it is domain or other bean, instead of looking for an workaround to map request param `empId` into `String id`, corresponding Command objects are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BindUsing annotation, see here http://docs.grails.org/2.3.5/api/org/grails/databinding/BindUsing.html